# Set subreport text object in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

I wanted to set the subreport header text via resource file.This the code i have tried below

```
  ReportDocument rDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportSource"];

 ((TextObject)rDocument.Subreports["HolidaySubReport"].ReportDefinition.
 ReportObjects["HolidaySchedule"]).Text=Resources.Resources.HolidaySchedule;
```

But here i am getting error as `object reference not set to instance of object`

How can i solve this issue.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which line you get this error?

Comment: The second line,when casting to `TextObject`

Comment: Have you check if HolidaySubReport exists in rDocument.Subreports?

Comment: Thankyou you was absolutely right.The problem was that i had given the the object name rather than subreport name

Answer (score 0):

```
TextObject txtpentotal = (TextObject)objRpt.Subreports["Subreport.rpt"].ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["txttotal"];
txtpentotal.Text = pen.Text;
```

Comment: Please add some text to describe your fix and what it does to solve the problem. Code-only answers are frowned on at stack overflow.